# how does UITextView delegate knows when to call textViewDidEndEditing

Tags: iphone, uitextview

I am developing an application in which i need to call a particular method when user hits  return button.I am using UITextView. Now the problem is that when I hit return key ,cursor goes to next line and I am not able to retrieve the action in my code. I tried to write the same code in 
textViewDidEndEditing: delegate method but it looks as if we cant find when and at what action this particular method is called...Can someone help in with any of above approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To detect the return key, you could implement the following delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
```

Simply check `text` for a newline and proceed as desired.